# Redefining \thepage and compatibility with standalone

Tags: formatting, standalone

**Backstory**

I'm currently working on a document that has got way to big to deal with so have split the chapters into separate documents that use the `standalone` class. In original document I was using chapter-page page numbering.

**Issue**

To make `\thepage` use chapter-page format I use:

```
%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother
```

When compiling the standalone chapters this works fine, however the master document won't compile due to an "incomplete \iffalse" which I can't find but have narrowed down to the page numbering modification.

I've tried placing the \thepage modification inside `\ifstandalone ... \fi` but this is also failing when compiling master but works fine in the standalone chapter.

I'm using pdflatex.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I realize that I can remove the mod and get normal page numbering for the standalone chapters and the chapter-page numbering when compiling master. This is now more of a curiosity thing...

**MWE of master:**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openleft]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[headsep=0.2cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\include{standalone_chapter1}
\include{standalone_chapter2}
\end{document}
```

**MWE Standalone Chapter:**

```
\documentclass[class=book,crop=false,float=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[headsep=0.2cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}


%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\chapter{Interesting topic}
Some really interesting content that won't make you yawn.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to put your patching code in an external file and use \input{mypagepatch} in the files.

Comment: The problem is that TeX scans for further `\if...` tokens inside a false clause and then looks for matching `\fi` tokens. Groups and argument braces are ignored. If you have `\iffalse ... \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{} ... \fi` then TeX missed two `\fi` statements! You need to hide the `\if...` statements from TeX, e.g. put them into a extra file like Ulrike.

Comment: Alternative try instead of `\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter` the following: `\expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter\@chapter\expandafter{\csname if@mainmatter \expandafter\endcsname\expandafter}\expandafter{\csname if@mainmatter\endcsname`. This creates the same `\patchcmd` call but does not include `\if...` tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hack, but you can move the problematic code *after* `\begin{document}` in the included file.

I use `filecontents*` to make the example self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_chapter1}
\documentclass[class=book,crop=false,float=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[headsep=0.2cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\begin{document}
%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\chapter{Interesting topic}
Some really interesting content that won't make you yawn.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openleft]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[headsep=0.2cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\include{\jobname_chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Or, as proposed, hide the conditional with

```
%% Makes the Page Numbers Chapter-Page
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter\@chapter\expandafter
  {\csname if@mainmatter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter}\expandafter
  {\csname if@mainmatter\endcsname\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother
```

The simplest way around is to build a simple `mypatches.sty` file

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypatches}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
```

and load it.